# How to use page item value inside a trigger query in oracle?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle19c

I want the following trigger to be run correctly but it rise an error which is: bad bind variable 'P23_ID'.
The trigger query is:

```
Create or replace trigger "newTRG"
Before
Insert on "my_table"
For each row
Begin
If :new."ID" is null then
Insert into my_table (ID) values (:P23_ID);
end if;
End;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `v()` syntax:

```
create or replace trigger "newTRG" before
   insert on "my_table"
   for each row
begin
   if :new."ID" is null then
      insert into my_table ( id ) values (v('P23_ID'));

   end if;
end;
```

On a side note, if this is a primary key value it is a lot easier to use identity columns (the new way) or a sequence (the old way) to populate your column. Doing this from a page item is error prone.

Comment: More info here https://svenweller.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/sequence-and-audit-columns-with-apex-5-and-12c/